# Filter Packet PPPoE Discovery

Tags: cisco, mac-address, cisco-nexus, route-filter

i have a sw nexus

i have a router BGN with vlan 50 is going to sw then mode access to Client 1 and Client 2

```
BNG ==== SW1 == PORT1 =Client 1 (Mode access vlan 50)

                PORT2 =Client 2 (Mode access vlan 50
```

)

the have connected to BNG by pppoe and everything is ok

but the problem is

when Client 1 try to connect  to BNG  , is send a PADI packet , it's a broadcast  , so this packet is going to Client 2 and to BNG Router

i need some filter apply in Port 1 ( outbound) so is just filter Any  PADI packet to go to client

so the Port 1 and 2 they just only can send PADI message and not do not receive it it from another Client .

Comment: What's the switch model? If you can't/don't want to put each client in a different VLAN you need to configure the VLAN as private. How that works depends on the switch features.

Comment: Hello , is nexus 3000 model

Comment: Any another idea except pvlan ? ,,,

Comment: Without PVLAN your clients can generally talk to one another outside of PPPoE - don't think you'd want that.

Comment: what about Mac access-list with ethertype

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is generally called "port isolation". On NX-OS, that's done with private vlans. Yes, at first glance, PVLAN configuration can be confusing, but Cisco has many documented examples. [Here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/layer2/configuration/guide/Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Layer_2_Switching_Configuration_Guide_Release_5-x_chapter6.html) is one such document. (old, and ignore that it's for a 7000 and v5_x)

```
vlan 3
  private-vlan isolated

vlan 2
  private-vlan primary
  private-vlan association 3

! ROUTER PORT
interface ethernet 1/1
  switchport
  switchport mode private-vlan promiscuous

! CLIENT1    
interface ethernet 1/2
  switchport
  switchport mode private-vlan host
  switchport private-vlan host-association 2 3

! CLIENT2
interface ethernet 1/3
  switchport
  switchport mode private-vlan host
  switchport private-vlan host-association 2 3

! Layer-3 interface (optional?)
interface vlan 2
  private-vlan mapping 3
```

You only need a primary and isolated vlan. The *primary* vlan carries traffic downstream to the isolated client ports. The *isolated* vlan carries traffic upstream from the isolated ports. That should prevent traffic between clients. However, broadcast traffic from the router (e1/1) would still be sent to all clients.

MAC filtering could also work, but would require knowing the MACs of all devices at all times. Any change in device would require updating the filters.

Comment: thank for helping ,but i can use same interface to trunk a normal vlan and Pvlan?